# When SAS script was last run

Tags: sas

Is there a way to find out when a script in SAS was last run? I have found many scripts in SAS and want to find out if they're still being used by others or whether they are obsolete.

Ideally, I'd like to find out either the date (and time if possible) or how long ago a script was last run.

Thanks

Comment: What is a SAS Script?

A SAS Program that is run in batch mode will produce a log file, and optionally a listing file or program output.  The date time on these file will give you an indication of when a program was last run.

If a program is run interactively in a client such as Display Manager the log file will not be saved automatically.

Running code on a SAS Server through clients such as Enterprise Guide, SAS Studio, Visual Analytics will be logged by the server.